# Authenticated Rest API used by a SPA : how to get CSRF token for login and registration forms?

Tags: angular, security, spring-security, single-page-application, csrf

I have a Single Page Application which consumes and authenticates on a rest api I am building.
The whole SPA is loaded without authentication.

I know what I will do with the csrf tokens once they are in the cookies.

For login and registration form I don't have a CSRF token yet since those are not server rendered pages.
Do I need to make a get endpoint '/loadCSRFTokens' just to load the cookies ?

What is the good practice? What do people usually do?

The tech I'm using are Angular and Spring-security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I posted the question I had two servers:

- 1 for loading the SPA
- 1 for all the rest API

I believe only the server from which you are loading the SPA can set cookies on your browser.
So since this server needs to be able to set cookies anyway it can do it in response of the request 'load SPA home page' and a '/loadCSRFTokens' endpoint is not needed.

I solved my problem by serving the SPA as a static content on one of the rest-API server's endpoint.